# Is there a way of pinpointing which line of code has a divide by zero error?

Tags: sql-server

I am encountering a Divide by zero error, starting at where the SELECT statement begins at, but not sure where exactly the error is. I have placed NULLIF( ,0) where there is division commands, but still returning the divide by zero error. Is there a way of pinpointing exactly where the error is triggered?

```
drop table #tempMAINA
SELECT a.COUNTRY_IBS 
      --,a.[List_Price_Code]                                        AS "LPC"
      ,a.[Item_Number]
      --,b.COUNTRY_IBS
      --,b.[Price_list]
      --,b.[Item_Number]
      ,Item.Item_Desc_English                                   AS "Item_Description"
      ,ITEM.Product_Manager_Name                                AS "Product_Manager"
      --,PMCD.Category_Director
      ,ITEM.Manufacturer
      ,ITEM.Manufacturer_Desc
      ,ITEM.Brand
      ,ITEM.Brand_Desc
      ,CMT.NAME_PRDUCT_CLASS_LEVEL_2                            AS "CMT_LEVEL_2"
      ,ITEM.PPG_Code
      ,ITEM.PPG_Desc
      ,TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]                                  AS "2019_Standard_List_LC"
      ,TLPC.Standard_List                                       AS "2020_Standard_List_LC"
      ,TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate                      AS "2020_Standard_List_USD"                                                                             
      ,sc2020.Standard_Cost                                     AS "2020_Standard_Cost_LC"
      ,sc2020.Standard_Cost*FX.Exchange_Rate                        AS "2020_Standard_Cost_USD"
      ,(TLPC.[Standard_List]-sc2020.[Standard_Cost])            AS "2020_Margin_per_Unit_LC"
      ,1-sc2020.[Standard_Cost]/NULLIF(TLPC.[Standard_List],0)          AS "Margin_as_%_of_Stan_List_LC"
      --,c.[Conversion_factor]                                  AS "Conv"
      ,CASE WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
            THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
            ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END                         AS "ASP_USD"
      ,CASE WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
            THEN    sc2020.[Standard_Cost]*FX.Exchange_Rate
            ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Cost_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)    END                         AS "ASCost_USD"

      ,CASE WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
            THEN    TLPC.Standard_List *FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
            ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END 
            - 
        CASE    WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
            THEN    sc2020.[Standard_Cost]*FX.Exchange_Rate
            ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Cost_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)    END                         AS Margin_per_Unit

     ,1- CASE   WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
            THEN    sc2020.[Standard_Cost]*FX.Exchange_Rate
            ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Cost_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)    END 
            /CASE   WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
            THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
            ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END                         AS "Margin_at_ASP_as_%_of_ASP"

      ,(1-(CASE WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
                THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
                ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0) END)
                /NULLIF(TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate,0))                                 AS "ASP_Discount_%"


      ,CASE WHEN TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD] > 0 
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END                                                       AS "Selling_History_Y/N"
      --,c.[Conversion_factor]                                                          AS "QDP_Quantity_Limit"

      ,CASE WHEN    [Number_of_Orders] IS NULL
            THEN    0
            ELSE    [Avg_Num_Units_per_Order]   END                                     AS "Avg. # Units per Order"     

      --,CASE WHEN [Avg_Num_Units_per_Order] IS NULL                    THEN c.[Conversion_factor]
            --WHEN [Avg_Num_Units_per_Order] > c.[Conversion_factor]    THEN CEILING([Avg_Num_Units_per_Order]/c.[Conversion_factor])
            --*c.[Conversion_factor]
            --ELSE c.[Conversion_factor] END                                                AS "Adjusted_QDP_Quantity_Limit"

      ,-((CASE WHEN [Number_of_Orders] IS NULL
            THEN    0
            ELSE    [Avg_Num_Units_per_Order]   END)
        --  /
        --CASE WHEN [Avg_Num_Units_per_Order] IS NULL                   THEN c.[Conversion_factor]
        --  WHEN [Avg_Num_Units_per_Order] > c.[Conversion_factor]  THEN CEILING([Avg_Num_Units_per_Order]/c.[Conversion_factor])
        --  *c.[Conversion_factor]
        --  ELSE c.[Conversion_factor] END)
        +
        (CASE WHEN (LTM_Qty-PTM_Qty)/NULLIF(LTM_Qty+PTM_Qty,0) IS NULL
              THEN 0
              ELSE (LTM_Qty-PTM_Qty)/NULLIF(LTM_Qty+PTM_Qty,0) END +1)/2)/2 + 1                 AS "GrowthNearQtyBreak"

      ,CASE WHEN TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD] IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD] END                                                AS "LTM_Sales_USD"
      ,CASE WHEN TSC.[LTM_Cost_USD] IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE TSC.[LTM_Cost_USD] END                                                 AS "LTM_Cost_USD"
      ,CASE WHEN TSC.[PTM_Sales_USD] IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE TSC.[PTM_Sales_USD] END                                                AS "PTM_Sales_USD"
      ,CASE WHEN Sales_Change IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE Sales_Change END                                                       AS "Sales_Change"
      ,(CASE WHEN -(TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD]-[PTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD]+[PTM_Sales_USD],0) IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE -(TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD]-[PTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD]+[PTM_Sales_USD],0) END
            +1)/2                                                                       AS "Sales Growth % (scaled)"      
      ,CASE WHEN LP_Change IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE LP_Change END                                                          AS "LP_Change"
      ,CASE WHEN ((TLPC.[Standard_List]-TLPC.[PY_Standard_List])
                    /
                 (TLPC.[Standard_List]+TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]) + 1)/2 IS NULL
            THEN 0.5
            ELSE ((TLPC.[Standard_List]-TLPC.[PY_Standard_List])
                    /
                 (TLPC.[Standard_List]+TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]) + 1)/2  END             AS "List Price % Change (scaled)"
      ,CASE WHEN    [LTM_Qty] IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE    [LTM_Qty] END                                                       AS "LTM_Qty"
      ,CASE WHEN    [PTM_Qty] IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE    [PTM_Qty] END                                                       AS "PTM_Qty"
      ,CASE WHEN Qty_Change IS NULL
            THEN 0
            ELSE Qty_Change END                                                         AS "Qty_Change"
INTO #tempMAINA
FROM #templistandMSLP           a
--LEFT JOIN #ListPrice                                                  FLP
--  ON FLP.Item_Number=a.Item_Number
--  AND FLP.Country_IBS=a.COUNTRY_IBS
--  AND FLP.RowID='1'

LEFT JOIN [DATA_IBS].[dbo].[dim_Item_ALL_COUNTRIES]     ITEM with (nolock)  
    ON ITEM.Item_Number=a.Item_Number
    AND a.COUNTRY_IBS=ITEM.Country_IBS

--LEFT JOIN [PROJECTS_EU_List_Price_Roll].[dbo].[Product_Manager_Category_Director] PMCD
--  ON PMCD.Product_Manager=ITEM.Product_Manager_Name

LEFT JOIN Projects_Price_Volume_EU.[dbo].[GWFS_DI_CMT_TAXONOMY_HIER_TB] cmt
    ON   cast(ITEM.Leaf_node as varchar) = cast(cmt.[ID_TAXONOMY_NODE] as varchar) 

LEFT JOIN #tempPP2019   c               /* Joining the Purchase Price table to limit Supplier to =10 and date's current with today */
    ON a.item_number = c.Item_Number
    AND a.country_ibs = c.country_ibs


LEFT JOIN [DATA_IBS].[dbo].[fact_Quantity_Dependent_List_Prices_all_all_countries] b    /* Joining the QDP List Price table to exclude those items that already have QDP Pricing */
    ON a.Item_Number = b.Item_Number
    AND a.country_ibs = b.country_ibs
    --AND a.List_Price_Code = b.Price_list

LEFT JOIN #tempQtyChange                                                TQC
    ON a.Item_Number = TQC.Sku
    AND a.COUNTRY_IBS = TQC.country_IBS

LEFT JOIN #tempSalesChange                                              TSC
    ON a.Item_Number = TSC.Sku
    AND a.COUNTRY_IBS = TSC.country_IBS

LEFT JOIN #tempLPChange                                                 TLPC
    ON a.Item_Number = TLPC.Item_Number
    AND a.COUNTRY_IBS = TLPC.country_IBS

LEFT JOIN PROJECTS_QDP.dbo.QDP_Candidates_Avg_Sales_by_PPG_Code_202005          CPPG            /* Joining QDP Candidate table with PPG Code Avg. Sales for ASP for those candidates with no selling history */
    ON ITEM.PPG_Code=CPPG.PPG_Code
    AND ITEM.PPG_Desc=CPPG.PPG_Desc

--LEFT JOIN PROJECTS_Price_Volume_EU.dbo.Price_Volume_Cube_Master_EUROPE_TB_2018_OldSalesOrg    PV
--  ON a.COUNTRY_IBS=PV.country_IBS
--  AND a.Item_Number=PV.sku

LEFT JOIN DATA_IBS.dbo.dim_Country_Defaults_ALL_COUNTRIES               CD
    ON a.COUNTRY_IBS=CD.Country_Code

LEFT JOIN DATA_IBS.dbo.fact_Exchange_Rates_ALL_ALL_COUNTRIES        FX
    ON CD.Default_Currency=FX.Currency_Code_From
    AND FX.Currency_Code_To='USD'
    and FX.period=202004
left join #StandardCost2020 sc2020
    on a.country_ibs=sc2020.country_ibs
    and a.item_number=sc2020.item_number
--left join #QDPItems as Qdp
--  on a.country_ibs=Qdp.country_ibs
--  and a.item_number=Qdp.sku

WHERE --a.List_Price_Code = '01'
    --AND c.Conversion_Factor <> 1    -- will find all records with conversion factor <> 1, some of which have a QDP price, some do not
     --b.Item_Number IS NULL        -- will find all records without current QDP List  Price
    --and Qdp.sku is null               -- will exclude current qdp items with sales
     Item.PPG_Desc <> 'Third Party Products          '
    AND TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate >= CASE WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
                                                    THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
                                                    ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END 
    AND CASE    WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
                THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
                ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END
        >
        CASE    WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
                THEN    sc2020.[Standard_Cost]*FX.Exchange_Rate
                ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Cost_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)    END
```

Comment: When you get a divide by zero error, it won't tell you the line. I suggest starting at the divisions where you don't have `NULLIF({Divisor},0)`, as there are several of them. (*P.s. Why are your aliases all the way over on the far right where no one can see them without scrolling?*)

Comment: Check out Margin_at_ASP_as_%_of_ASP. The CASE statement you have for the denominator can produce that error.

Comment: Wow, do you really expect anyone to plough through that monster of an expression?!? :D
What about dividing it into smaller, more digestable portions?

Comment: Additional side note: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). For example, `fact_Quantity_Dependent_List_Prices_all_all_countries` doesn't have a single `b` in it, so why is its alias `b`? (also, that is a really long object name).

Answer (score 1):

I see only two possible places:

The bottom of this division expression could work out to zero if `TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD]` is zero and `tqc.[LTM_Qty]` is not zero:

```
1- CASE   WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
        THEN    sc2020.[Standard_Cost]*FX.Exchange_Rate
        ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Cost_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)    END 
        /CASE   WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
        THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
        ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END
```

Also this expression, the bottom of both the `WHEN` and `ELSE` parts could be zero if `TLPC.[Standard_List]+TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]` is zero (or perhaps -1, if I'm reading the order of the operations wrong):

```
  ,CASE WHEN ( (TLPC.[Standard_List]-TLPC.[PY_Standard_List])
                /
              (TLPC.[Standard_List]+TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]) + 1
            )/2 IS NULL
        THEN 0.5
        ELSE ((TLPC.[Standard_List]-TLPC.[PY_Standard_List])
                /
             (TLPC.[Standard_List]+TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]) + 1)/2  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Lines I found that could produce divide by zero:

`"Margin_at_ASP_as_%_of_ASP"`

```
.../CASE   WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
            THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
            ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END
```

either the THEN or the ELSE could result in 0.

`"List Price % Change (scaled)"`

```
CASE WHEN ((TLPC.[Standard_List]-TLPC.[PY_Standard_List])
                    /
                 (TLPC.[Standard_List]+TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]) + 1)/2 IS NULL
           THEN 0.5
            ELSE ((TLPC.[Standard_List]-TLPC.[PY_Standard_List])
                    /
                 (TLPC.[Standard_List]+TLPC.[PY_Standard_List]) + 1)/2  END
```

Both the WHEN and the ELSE could result in 0.

Side note -- did I just search for every `/` for you and find all the ones without `nullif`?

Answer (score 0):

Two simple but manual tricks:

Option 1: comment out all the output fields, then uncomment them one by one and run the query until the error occurs. You should be able to find out the field or expression causing the error but it may not be the only one.

Option 2: limit your resultset with TOP 10, TOP 1000 etc until you trigger the error. Then decrement the number of records until the error goes away. It would be good to include the IDs for all the joined tables, so that you can pinpoint the records involved. And also sort by IDs. If the error occurs after ID 999 then you know the next ID (1000 or whatever) is probably where the problem begins.

I would start with option #1. When you have identified a problematic expression, output the individual fields/values separately. Everything should become clear.

If for example you notice that this expression is crashing:

```
  ,CASE WHEN    TQC.[LTM_Qty] IS NULL OR TQC.[LTM_Qty]=0
        THEN    TLPC.Standard_List*FX.Exchange_Rate*(1-CPPG.[Discount Percentage])
        ELSE    (TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD])/NULLIF(tqc.[LTM_Qty],0)   END                         AS "ASP_USD"
```

Then output those columns:

```
TQC.[LTM_Qty],
TLPC.Standard_List,
FX.Exchange_Rate,
CPPG.[Discount Percentage],
TSC.[LTM_Sales_USD]
```

And look at the values, in particular `tqc.[LTM_Qty]`.